# Using CSS background image to output grid using gradient with offset

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I need to output a repeating background grid using CSS.

I've managed to use the [repeating-linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) function in order to do so, and it's displayed great:

[image]

Then, however, I need to shift the grid on horizontal axis by 100px.

I've added [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) property to do so:

[image]

But, in the end, it gives me a weird result. Some extraneous vertical line is drawn.

Interestingly enough, this line is fixed to the computer screen, so if you resize that window, you can see that this line is not moving with it. [I've recorded a video to demonstrate](https://youtu.be/-woD8OFJWKU).

Why is it happening exactly and how do I counter this behavior?

Is there some alternative way to draw such a grid shifted by offset?

[Please, take a look at this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slavafomin/Lgkm4fxp/).

And here's the code I'm using:

```css
:root {
  --background-grid-color: deeppink;
  --background-fill-color: #000;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* Vertical lines */
  background-color: var(--background-fill-color);
  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to right,
      var(--background-grid-color) 0,
      var(--background-grid-color) 1px,
      transparent 1px,
      transparent 200px
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      var(--background-grid-color) 0,
      var(--background-grid-color) 1px,
      transparent 1px,
      transparent 200px
    )
  ;
  background-position: 100px 0, 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by using `background-size` and `linear-gradient` instead of `repeating-linear-gradient`:

```
:root {
  --background-grid-color: deeppink;
  --background-fill-color: #000;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* Vertical lines */
  background-color: var(--background-fill-color);
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      var(--background-grid-color) 0,
      var(--background-grid-color) 1px,
      transparent 1px,
      transparent 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      var(--background-grid-color) 0,
      var(--background-grid-color) 1px,
      transparent 1px,
      transparent 100%
    )
  ;
  background-position: 100px 0, 0 0;
  background-size: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what caused this artifact in the first place, probably it's somehow related to the background size.

Finally, I've managed to overcome this problem by adding the following CSS properties for both background-images:

```css
background-size: 200px 200px, 200px 200px;
```

Comment: In this case the `repeating-linear-gradient` repeats exactly once. Why not use `linear-gradient` then?

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is a great optimization. That's why I've accepted your answer. I've just posted my answer at the same time.